# Mac Mini - Monitor gets no signal everytime Mac wakes from sleep

Tags: display, sleep, mac-mini, signal

Everything works fine until the Mac goes to sleep, then upon waking it the monitor (Wacom Cintiq interactive pen display) gets no signal and I have to unplug it from the back of the mac and plug it in again.  Then it gets signal again and works. The Mac wakes and operates without a problem

I have downloaded the latest drivers for the display and the OS. Using OS X 10.6.2

Comment: Does this problem appear with other displays?

Comment: Has this EVER worked propery, or was this a problem from day one?

Answer (score 2):

I would contact [Wacom](http://www.wacom.com/productsupport/) about this. It doesn't sound like an issue with the computer but rather with the Cintiq display.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I connected another monitor and tested it and it didnt happen, although I am not 100% sure of the conditions required for the problem to occur.  Sometimes the display would re-awake with the Mac and sometimes it wouldnt, i'm not sure if it requires a certain length of time asleep etc. But I gave it a good test on the new monitor.

To answer the other question it has always been a problem, I have had this set up for 2 months.

I'll attempt to contact Wacom directly about this and update here with whatever they offer.

Answer (score 1):

That happens occasionally with my secondary Samsung monitor (an old VGA flatscreen connected to my Mac Pro through a DisplayPort > VGA adapter) so I'm not sure it's a Cintiq problem. I'm not sure what causes it... but I've discovered that when it happens:

1. Powering the monitor off and on again doesn't help.
2. Unplugging the monitor's data cable and replugging the cable wakes it up, but there's an easier way...
3. Keep the Displays icon showing in your menu bar. When the second monitor fails to wake, just change its refresh rate (like from 60 Hz to 70 Hz) and then back again, if you like. That seems to jog it awake and is a lot easier than messing around with the cables.